# Throw Exception Whenever Package Protected Static Method Is Called Using PowerMock (EasyMock)

Tags: java, powermock, easymock

I'm trying to throw an assertion exception whenever the TimeZone.getDefaultRef() method is called, to basically show that this method is never called during the test. The problem is that it's package protected and static, so I think I'm forced to use PowerMock. Here's my attempt:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TimeZone.class)
public class RandomTestingClass {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        PowerMock.mockStaticPartialNice(TimeZone.class, "getDefaultRef")
        PowerMock.expectPrivate(TimeZone.class, 
            TimeZone.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDefaultRef")).andStubThrow(new AssertionError());
        PowerMock.replay(TimeZone.class)
    }

    @Test
    public void randomTestThatShouldFailBecauseMethodCallsGetDefaultRefMethod() {
        Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    @Test
    public void randomTestThatShouldPassBecauseMethodDoesNotCallGetDefaultRefMethod() {
        Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        PowerMock.verify(TimeZone.class);
    {
```

I'm getting the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available, which I've definitely seen before but am not sure how to fix in this context. I'm also open to any other more elegant way to accomplish this. To sum up:

1. Test should fail if `Timezone.getDefaultRef()` is ever called
2. Test shouldn't fail just because the method is never called (EasyMock is expecting the method but it never comes)
3. One test failing shouldn't affect the other tests
4. Everything else about the TimeZone class should operate normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to find a workaround but the quick answer is that the method is not mocked. The real method is called instead during the expectation.

PowerMock can't mock classes loaded by the bootstrap class loader. `TimeZone` is one of those.

The solution is to mock with is calling it. It's explained [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System). It says you need to prepare the class calling the system class instead of the system class.

But in your case, I'm not sure you can. Because you want to know if something somewhere is calling your class. So you can't prepare whatever is using `TimeZone` if that is was you are looking for. Unless you have a limited scope of possible callers.

Comment: Thank you again. I found this stack overflow answer that might provide some clues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786034/how-to-load-java-util-timezone-more-then-once-in-jvm

Since it is delegated to the sun.util class, then would using Powermock on that be a viable strategy for accomplishing this?

Comment: Ok. I've found what I was looking for. So I have updated my answer. But I don't think you have an easy solution sadly. Unless you use ByteBuddy or Byteman or something like that.

Comment: Hi Henri, first of all, thank you again for really going above and beyond with this. That's the answer that I was looking for (but not hoping for). I was looking into AspectJ  runtime weaving with annotation but I think that at this point, it would be better just to go through the codebase manually and search for all of the offending methods, instead of trying this somewhat haphazard automated approach. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. AspectJ will have the same problem I think. Unless it can now use a Java agent. The simple alternative is to put a breakpoint where you do not want to be and if you never stop in the breakpoint, you are fine. Of course, this is not automated testing...

Comment: Ah, for some reason, I didn't even consider the breakpoint. Not quite automated, but a good sanity check for after I go through a class and fix everything, to make sure it's not still there.